# Question about designing a job ad

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, jobs

We're trying to design a job ad and I'm struggling with it. The job is something like a full stack developer and data scientist who will be working as a tool smith for an analyst team.

Where should I ask for advice on how to design a job ad?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid the scope of your question is **too limited** to be of general value, and most Stack Exchange sites that in one way or another deal with this topic will close it. A question about advice to design a job ad for an IT position in general, while more generally applicable, could be too broad. In general, asking for advice is a rather tricky topic, as it often leads to *opinion-based* answers. The Stack Exchange Q&A format works better with objective answers.

For example, [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) has [questions about advertisements](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advertisement), but is more focused towards how ads in general integrate with the rest of a website or app. They close review questions as off-topic precisely because of their limited usefulness for the general public.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. In order to minimize opinion-based answers I would say that I can describe the job but I do not know the name of it (e.g. full stack vs data scientist vs data analyst...). Perhaps an objective answer would be a link to a site giving the descriptions of such roles.